# Freemarker Template with Struts framework

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, struts, freemarker

I am new to ftl and struts framework. I am trying to make index.ftl as welcome page and has mentioned it in web.xml.

But when I'm running my project it is displayin error 403 that is access denied error.
Please help me why I'm unable to make an ftl as welcome page and why this error is occuring ?

The same project is working appropriately while I'm making index.jsp as welcome file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you mapped properly your action of the struts to a index.ftl??? something like...

---

```
Struts.xml
<action name="homepage" class="someJavaFile.class">
       <result name="homePage" type="freemarker">
        <param name="location">/ftl/index.ftl</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

---

someJavaFile.java

```
//......Some Code........
public static string execute()
{
      //----Some Code-----
      return "homePage";
}
```

Comment: When I'm using jsp as a welcome page,I'm not doing any mapping in actions.In the welcome jsp page I'm only redirecting the control to some other page. why it is needed for ftl welcome page ?

Comment: It is only needed when you want to show different welcome pages to the different people. As a example, you are creating a B2B portal. When buyers come to your website (E.G. from some AFFILIATES) THEN you want to show them some different welcome page... while in the case of sellers you want another welcome page...

Comment: Okay , But in my case I'm not displaying more then one welcome pages. I want to display an ftl page as a welcome page.